# Bus Routes: obtaining multiple routes from only 2 stops per route

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, graph-algorithm

So I have a list of routes a bus can take and the distance for each one:

```
routes = {'AB':5, 'BC':4, 'CD':8, 'DC':8, 'DE':6, 'AD':5, 'CE':2, 'EB':3, 'AE':7}
```

or just as a list for now since distance isn't important just yet:

```
paths = ['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DC', 'DE', 'AD', 'CE', 'EB', 'AE']
```

Now I'm trying to get a list of the possible routes that the bus can take given the starting and ending points and then I want to try incorporate a max number of stops to limit the data output. At the moment I have this so far for a function:

```
def route_variations(first_stop, last_stop, max_stops):
    possiblepaths = []

    for path in paths:
        x = path[0]     #first letter of each route
        if first_stop == x:
            possiblepaths.append(path)

    for path in paths:
        y = path[-1]    #last letter of each route
        if last_stop == y:
            possiblepaths.append(path)
    return possiblepaths
```

So if I wanted to start and end at C for example

```
route_variations('C','C', 10)
```

would return a list of routes starting with C and ending with C ie. -> ['CD', 'CE', 'BC', 'DC']

So now I need connection routes as well. The route C-E-B-C needs the E-B route which I'm missing from my output. Any idea how to start implementing that? And then joining them to achieve full routes like CDC instead of CD and DC?

Comment: I think you need to look at how to make a graph. :)

Comment: It might be easier to use a dictionary for `paths` rather than your current list. The keys could be the vertices and the values could be lists of vertices which are reachable from the key in 1 step. (I might prefer to call the result `links` or perhaps `edges` or `arrows` rather than `paths`). Using such a dictionary, it would be easy to use breadth-first search to build up the paths that you are looking for.

Comment: You might want to make a nodes-and-edges data structure as used in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Comment: SO is not a place to ask for off-site resources.  Please search for "Python graph tutorial" or some related items.  We have no way of knowing which resources, out of the thousands existing on the topic, will be particularly useful for you.  Also, as the posting guidelines tell you, we expect you to perform this level of research for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are well known algorithms in graph theory for finding paths, as the comments on your question suggest.

But, just for the sake of learning (seriously, just for the sake of learning, this code is not really suitable for the general case of this task), I'll try providing a simple example that is structured somewhat like your code, so you can see what you were missing for getting those "connection routes"

The basic principle is when you find a correct path (by comparing the first letter) you look for all routes that begin with this path, by calling the function again, from within itself (i.e. recursion), with the second letter of the path.:

```py
paths = ['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DC', 'DE', 'AD', 'CE', 'EB', 'AE']


def route_variations(first_stop, last_stop, max_stops):
    possible_routes = []
    if max_stops == 0 or first_stop == last_stop:
        return possible_routes
    for path in paths:
        x,y = path
        if first_stop == x:
            if last_stop == y:
                possible_routes.append([path])
            routes_from_this_stop = route_variations(y, last_stop, max_stops - 1)
            possible_routes.extend([[path] + route for route in routes_from_this_stop])
    return possible_routes


print(route_variations('A', 'C', 10))
```

the Output is:

```
[['AB', 'BC'], ['AD', 'DC'], ['AD', 'DE', 'EB', 'BC'], ['AE', 'EB', 'BC']]
```

**NOTE:** if there are circles in the route, you'll get many similar routes going around the circle (limited in length by `max_stops`).

**NOTE 2:** this will not work when start and stop are the same, you'll get an empty result, so your specific example won't work here :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with itertools and permutations. It is probably not the fastest way if you want to run it for a high number of bus stops, but it works reasonably fast for combinations of until 8 stops.

As an output you get a dictionary with a simplified version of the route and the total distance:

```
import itertools

paths = ['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DC', 'DE', 'AD', 'CE', 'EB', 'AE']
routes = {'AB':5, 'BC':4, 'CD':8, 'DC':8, 'DE':6, 'AD':5, 'CE':2, 'EB':3, 'AE':7}

def route_variations(first_stop, last_stop, max_length):
    valid_routes = []
    for n in list(range(2, max_length+1)):
        combinations = itertools.product(paths, repeat=n)
        for combination in combinations:
            print (combination)
            for i in list(range(n)):
                if i == 0:
                    if combination[i][0] != first_stop:
                        break
                elif i != 0 and i != n-1:
                    if combination[i][0] != combination[i-1][1]:
                        break
                elif i == n-1:
                    if combination[i][0] == combination[i-1][1] and combination[i][1] == last_stop:
                        valid_routes.append(combination)
                    else:
                        break
    result = {}
    for route in valid_routes:
        route_simple = ""
        dist = 0
        for j in route:
            dist += routes.get(j)
            if route.index(j) == 0:
                route_simple += str(j)
            else:
                route_simple += str(j[1])
        result[route_simple] = dist

    return result


print(route_variations('A', 'C', 6))
```